# What kind of memory does the PDC09 Laptop have

Tags: laptop, upgrade, memory

The PDC09 Acer laptop has only 2GB of memory. I see that it DDR3 1066MHZ but it doesn't say if it's SDRAM or not. Anyone know. Would

[http://www.amazon.com/KTLTCS102G-Kingston-DDR3-1066-PC3-8500-240-pin/dp/B001DPRP2W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DPRP2W)

be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DDR3 is SDRAM.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM

> DDR3 SDRAM or double-data-rate three synchronous dynamic random access memory

As long as you get DDR3 memory that is the recommended speed or faster, you should be ok.

No, that ram you linked to will not work. That is for a full size desktop computer with DDR3 (notice it is 240pins).  You want DDR3 SO-DIMMS 204 pin with at least a 1066mhz speed rating.

See here: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=ddr3+1066+sodimm

Also, check out http://www.crucial.com and punch in that laptop (or any computer) and they will tell you exactly what you need to buy and what is the max supported. It is good for double checking you are buying the correct ram.

Comment: Guess I was a little DIMM on that one. Thanks for the info...